# Errors binding checkbox to $scope

Tags: angularjs

I have a checkbox, like:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="isPreCheckIn" />
```

I'm getting `isPreCheckin` (boolean) from a service which uses `$q` and either returns from the server or `localStorage` (if it exists).

The call in the controller looks like:

```
deviceSettings.canCheckIn().then(function (canCheckIn) {
    $scope.isPreCheckin = !canCheckIn ? true : false;
});
```

And `deviceSettings.canCheckIn` looks like:

```
function canCheckIn() {
    var dfrd = $q.defer();
    LoadSettings().then(function (success) {
        return dfrd.resolve(localStorage.canCheckIn);
    });

    return dfrd.promise;
};
```

So, on first page load, the checkbox doesn't bind correctly to `isPreCheckIn`; in fact, if I do a `{{isPreCheckIn}}`, it doesn't either.  If I switch off of that page and go back, it works.

Comment: Missing `()` -> `!canCheckIn() ? true : false`

Comment: canCheckIn, in the sense you're referring to, is what's returned from the promise, it's not calling the function again

Answer (score 1):

It appears that canCheckIn is outside of angular, based on that assumption, you need to wrap your assignment within $scope.apply:

```
deviceSettings.canCheckIn().then(function (canCheckIn) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        $scope.isPreCheckin = !canCheckIn ? true : false;
    });
});
```

This tells angular to recognize the changes on your $scope and apply to your UI.

Comment: I get that `$digest already in progress`, possibly because this is called on page load.  But I see what you're saying -- definitely has something to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap the following in a $apply:

```
function canCheckIn() {
  var dfrd = $q.defer();
  LoadSettings().then(function (success) {
    scope.$apply(function() {
      dfrd.resolve(localStorage.canCheckIn);
    }
  });
  return dfrd.promise;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a timing issue. You may need to put a resolve clause in your route to give this call time to run and then pass in the result as a DI value. Without knowing which router you are using it is impossible to give you an accurate answer, but you might look at the video on egghead.io regarding [routes and resolve](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-resolve).